# How to create sequential ID numbers in Access 2016 that will be continued from previous numbers of current data?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

My data is being taken from Excel Tables and a messy Access Database.

I have cleaned up the data using PowerQuery in Excel.  As such the information going into the creation of a new functional database in Access 2016.  Currently have ID numbers linking the various tables together already in excel and I would like these linkages to carry over to excel to help with the design of queries and forms to ensure their functionality.

What I need is a method to add autonumbers/ID numbers to the various tables AFTER the initial data is uploaded.

Therefore the numbers need to continue from last number in each associated table, when new information is added.

Is there a way to set the database to do this to automatically?

I tried to set the ID field to AutoNumber, but it overwrites the original ID numbers which means none of the tables will properly link to each other.

I have tried to set the field to autonumber AFTER adding the information, but the system won't allow that.

I am assuming I will be stuck using VBA and forms to do this, but I honestly don't know how.  It seems that no one has ever asked this question before as my google search keeps coming up empty.

Please note, management wants an Access Database, so no I cannot keep it in Excel.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: So you want to change the primary and foreign key links to autonumber/number instead of using the linking data from Excel? Why? Need to import with the Excel keys and autonumber field to generate values then run UPDATE action SQL to populate foreign key field in related tables. Is this a one-time exercise just to get Access established?

Comment: https://cdacomputer.tips/converting-number-data-to-autonumber-data-in-access/#:~:text=Click%20the%20Structure%20Only%20button,Press%20Ctrl%20%2B%20S%20to%20Save.

Comment: No, I have numbers that are being put into access already.  I want Access to create NEW numbers for any new item added to a table.  So self populate the ID field.

Comment: Thank you TIM WILLIAMS!!