# Autoincrementation of numbers attribute, that isn't an ID in ACCESS

Tags: database, ms-access, attributes, auto-increment, custom-data-attribute

Is there any possibilities to make an Autoincrementation type of attribute, that isn't an ID in ACCESS Data Base? It is possible to have in access two auto-number fields/attributes? Does identifier of the new record, that after adding into the Access database, can apeared also in another attribute?

Can this be done in such a way that it does not crash while checking the previously given records where occurs the duplication of numbers?

I mean the situation, when adding a new record, increments not only the ID, but also a different number's attribute.

Comment: almost the same problem I Saw here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63399383/8745419 , but I need to know how to make the second attribute (first is obviously Primary key) as Autoincreamet option

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What does 'to limit it to a specific problem'?